# If similar item exists in array remove and then add it , else just push it

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays ,one which stores many items and other will have only one item to check.
Both array will have same parameters but I want to check on new array two parameters "TaskId" and "ResourceId" , if the two parameters matches with main array , I want to remove and then add the new array.

Eg :

```
var mainArray = [{'Name':'Ticket1','TaskId':'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'Completed'},{'Name':'Ticket2','TaskId':'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'},{'Name':'Ticket3','TaskId':'45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'}];

var tmpArray = [{'TaskId':'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1','Status':'Pending'}];
```

Here in tmpArray there will always be one item ,

I want to check on basis of TaskId and ResourceId , if similar item matches in mainArray then remove that item and update it with the new one or may be simply update it with new one.

i.e My final array should be like

```
 [{'Name':'Ticket1','TaskId':'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'Pending'},{'Name':'Ticket2','TaskId':'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'},{'Name':'Ticket3','TaskId':'45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'}];
```

Here first item is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an item to check that is in your temp array:

```
var item = tmpArray[0];
```

Simply iterate over your main array and check for a match.If no match is found, push to the array.

```
function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].resourceID === item.resourceID && arr[i].taskID === item.taskID) {
      // DO STUFF 
      return;
    }
  }

  mainArray.push(item);
}
```

Now, it is a little unclear as to what you actually want to do if a match is found. Assuming you always want to update with the object in the temp array, you can just replace the current item:

```
arr[i] = item;
```

If you only want to target some parameters, change them explicitly:

```
arr[i].status = item.status;
```

If you want to change an arbitrary number of parameters, you will have to iterate over your object's parameters and change each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
mainArray.forEach(function (ticket) {
    if (ticket.TaskId === tmpArray[0].TaskId && ticket.ResourceId === tmpArray[0].ResourceId)  {
        ticket.Status = tmpArray[0].Status;
    }
});

console.log(mainArray);
```

not faster, but simple.

Answer (score 0):

MainArray looks like an array of arrays. Loop through each item of MainArray with .pop until each is a separate array, then loop through each separate array using .shift to eliminate index 1. Then loop again with the == operator to find the matching array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because of the short circuit.

```js
function update(array, temp) {
    temp.forEach(function (a) {
        array.some(function (b, i, bb) {
            if (a.TaskId === b.TaskId && a.ResourceId === b.ResourceId) {
                bb[i] = a;
                return true;
            }
        }) || array.push(a);
    });
}

var mainArray = [{ 'Name': 'Ticket1', 'TaskId': 'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'Completed' }, { 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'InProgress' }, { 'Name': 'Ticket3', 'TaskId': '45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'InProgress' }],
    tmpArray = [{ 'TaskId': 'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'Pending' }];

update(mainArray, tmpArray);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(mainArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```